# BeautifulSoup - Finding Logos

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working on an automated program to identify website logos using BeautifulSoup and Python 3. For the first step I am looking for images that have the term 'logo' in their image name. It actually works decently. However, I want to expand this to an image who may contain the term image or is contained in a link with a class/id/attribute that says logo, or is even deeper buried in a link in a div that contains a class of 'logo'. For example:

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="http://www.mexgrocer.com/">
        <img src="http://ep.yimg.com/ca/I/mex-grocer_2269_22595" width="122" height="72" border="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" alt="Mexican Food">
    </a>
</div>
```

My code right now is:

```
img = soup.find("img",src=re.compile(r'logo',re.I))
```

How can I expand this to search through all of the parent tag attributes?

Answer (score 1):

use `find_all` to find all particular tag in whole document. you can try like this

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
import urllib2
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('your_url').read())
for x in soup.find_all(id='logo'):
    try:
        if x.name == 'img':
            print x['src']
    except:pass
```

if you want to search on class, just use class='logo'

Comment: But how can you search all possible attributes?

Comment: all possible means, like id,class style,name etc??

Comment: you can use `attrs`. try  like this `soup.find_all(attrs={'id':'id_value', 'name':'name_value', 'class':'class_name'})`

Answer (score 1):

The answer of this question need to be updated to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd


def getLogoSrc(url):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('your_url').read())
  for x in soup.find_all(id='logo'):
      try:
          if x.name == 'img':
              print(x['src'])
      except:
          pass
```

Comment: Hi! Could you briefly explain what was the problem with the old answer and what is added on top, with this answer?

Comment: I found two minor things, first in the import of BeautifulSoup, it was like this ---> Beautifulsoup, which gives you an error, and the second is that urllib2 ws updated and the import of urlopen from urllib2 not longer exists.

Comment: Nice finding! It would be nice to submit this change as an edit request to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find_all(tag,atributte), for example:

```
from bs4 import Beautifulsoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

var =soup.find_all("font",color="#990000") //all <font color=#990000></font> 
var2 = soup.find_all("a",class_="LinkIndex") // all <a class="LinkIndex"></a>
```